# AccessDenied on aws cp for bucket that encrypts objects with SSE KMS

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to download an SSE-KMS encrypted object from my S3 bucket `secret-bucket`, where my AWS account id is `XXXXXXXX` with command

```
aws s3 cp s3://secret-bucket/file.json ./file.json
```

IAM user policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

S3 bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "access",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "get-access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::secret-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::secret-bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

KMS key policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "bucket-key-default-1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow administration of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:root"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Apparently I'm missing some permissions somewhere, but can't seem to figure out which one. Any ideas?